# multiple declaration of firebase reference variable in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
DatabaseReference myRef;
FirebaseDatabase database;
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ne :dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                NewUser nne = ne.getValue(NewUser.class);

              //  txt.setText((CharSequence) nne);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

I am working on second activity and in my first activity I got the name,email,mobile etc for a new user. Now, I want to get the auth user info in my 2nd activity which is this. So kindly tell me how to code for this. How to use myRef in the 2 activity as I am getting null pointer exception.

Comment: You haven't initialized `myRef` in this code. Without initializing that will indeed throw a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialized your `DatabaseReference` and `FirebaseDatabase`. You can achieve this in a single line of code line this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Hope it helps.